# How To Tell If WCF Service Is Running At Host?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have a C# application that is self hosting a WCF service. I want to add a button click event in the application that lets the user know if the service is running/being hosted. Is there a way to detect if the service is running/hosted?

In case someone wants to see it, here is the code I am using to start hosting the service:

```
        private static void RunService()
    {
        System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost host = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(typeof(AccountingOperationsService.AccountingOperationsService));
        System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDebugBehavior debug = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDebugBehavior>();
        // if not found - add behavior with setting turned on 
        if (debug == null)
        {
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(
                 new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDebugBehavior() { IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true });
        }
        else
        {
            // make sure setting is turned ON
            if (!debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults)
            {
                debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            host.Open();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            string errorMessage = ex.Message + Environment.NewLine;
            errorMessage += ex.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine;

            DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraMessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error Starting Service", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, you need create method `Ping` in wcf service.

```
public bool Ping()
{
    return true;
}
```

and in application call `Ping`

```
bool itsWork;
try
{
    itsWork = service.Ping();
}
catch(Exception ex){}
```